# How to change the color of individual radio buttons in drupal 8 webform

Tags: webforms

I want to change the appearance of a Drupal 8 webform (version 8.x-5.8) radio element as per the options. Basically, the radio element is being visually presented as buttons and I was able to theme the buttons. However, this is a site where we are looking to collect responses from patients on their symptom severity and I would like to know if there is a way where I can color code the options like 
Red color for the button that says Severe, Blue Color that says Mild etc.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34854325

Answer (score 0):

I achieved this using webform custom elements module. Copied the button type element and then in the HTML added the value to the button class such that button with value 1 will have a class .btn-1 and with value 2 will have a class .btn-2. Then applied different css background colors to the buttons.

Other sites mention that the value attribute can be used with css like this .btn[value="1"] to ensure that css styling can be customized as per button value but it did not seem to work in this.